# Nested NSArray into UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, json, uitableview, nsarray

i have looked everywhere for this, but i am unable to find the exact answer... all have slight variations.

Anyway, i call a json page that returns the following (from the NSLog):

```
{
    messages =         {
        1 =             {
            Body = "This is the body of message 1";
            Title = "Message 1";
        };
        2 =             {
            Body = "This is the body of message 2";
            Title = "Message 2";
        };
    };
}
```

I then save the data into a NSDictionary (called messageArray). (the array is a NSMutableArray)

then i do:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    //put rowsarray into dictionary
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    //new dictionary into array
    NSArray *messages = [dictionary objectForKey:@"messages"];

    NSLog(@"the message array = %@",messages );

    //this fails
    cell.textLabel.text = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

the returned NSLog (so i am assuming my json array is working correctly):

```
the message array = {
1 =     {
    Body = "This is the body of message 1";
    Title = "Message 1";
};
2 =     {
    Body = "This is the body of message 2";
    Title = "Message 2";
};
```

}

I understand that i am not labelling the textlabels.text correctly, but i am not sure how to go about looping through the "messages" array, to display all the "Title" values from the array, to display on my UITableView list.

i am certain i am missing something so simple... but it has eluded me until now. Any links welcome... i will keep searching myself....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *messages = [dictionary objectForKey:@"messages"];
```

what is the need of this line if you get your dictionary here

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

now, you know what are the keys for attaching data to dictionary.

then simply

```
cell.textLabel.text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Title"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text= [dictionary valueForKey:@"Body"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This call

```
cell.textLabel.text = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

looks like it is returning a dictionary, and you are trying to stuff it into a test field.  I would confirm that this is a dictionary first, something like:

```
NSLog(@"%@",  [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])
```

If that is not a string, that may be your problem.

To get the string you want, you might do something like:

```
 [[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Title"]
```

Comment: i have added this line: NSLog(@"%@", [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);, and there is no love. i get the unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
cell.detailTextLabel.detailLabel = [[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Body"];
```

Comment: i have tried both the ideas of setting the textLabel, and i am getting nothing. I think i have to look at my dictionary and/or getting a string.

Comment: what are you using to convert the json object to a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

i have "semi" sorted the issue. I have removed the indexes from the json data so now it looks like:

```
messages =     (
            {
        Body = "This is the body of message 1";
        Title = "Message 1";
    },
            {
        Body = "This is the body of message 2";
        Title = "Message 2";
    }
);
```

And have used this for the populating of the table:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    //put rowsarray into dictionary
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSLog(@"dictionary = %@", dictionary );

    //new dictionary into array
    NSArray *messages = [dictionary objectForKey:@"messages"];

    //NSArray *message=[[messages allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSLog(@"array messages = %@", messages );

    cell.textLabel.text = [[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"]; 

    return cell;
}
```

i hope this helps someone.